# Unused String Variable

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of your favorite insect: ");
    String userString = input.next();

    String lyric = "";
    String endlyric = "";
    String OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;
    String Two = "Won't my Mommy be so proud of me";
    int count = 5;

    while (count != 0)
    {

        if (count == 5)
        {

            lyric = "bringing home ";
            endlyric = "OUCH!! It stung me!!";
            count = count - 1;

        } else if (count == 4)
        {
            lyric = "squishin' ";
            endlyric = "ICK!! I feel sick!!";
            count = count - 1;

        } else if (count == 3) {
            lyric = "barfin ";
            endlyric = "OH!! What a mess!!";
            count = count - 1;
        }

        else if (count == 2)
        {
            lyric = "wipin' ";
            endlyric = "OOPS!! Mommy's new towel!!";
            count = count - 1;
        }

        else if (count == 1)
        {
            lyric = "wringin' ";
            endlyric = "Bye-Bye baby "+userString+ "!!";
            count = count - 1;
        }

        System.out.println(OneThree);
        System.out.println(Two);
        System.out.println(OneThree);
        System.out.println(endlyric);
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
}
```

For some odd reason the lyric variable will not print... I get an error that states that it is unused. I have initialized the variable. the other variables work fine but that one please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `lyric` variable anywhere in your code after assigning its value. You do use it before it is initialized to a non empty value.

`String OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;` will become `"I'm my baby " +userString;`, since at the point that it's assigned, `lyric` is empty. The fact that you change `lyric` later to be non empty doesn't make a difference, since you never access it again after the assignment.

You could initialize `OneThree` to :

String OneThree = "I'm {0} my baby " +userString;

And then, instead of `System.out.println(OneThree);` do `System.out.println(String.format(OneThree,lyric));`.
That would put the current value of `lyric` in the String.

Comment: Java always initializes its variables, but he is here.

Comment: @drakej fixed my answer. he initializes it to empty String

Answer (score 1):

To add to Eran's answer:

The value:

```
String OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;
```

Does not update when lyric and userString change, it is a one time setting.

Update it in your loop, and you will see the change when printed.

Answer (score 0):

package com.freelancej;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of your favorite insect: ");
    String userString = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");

    String lyric = "";
    String endlyric = "";
    String OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;
    String Two = "Won't my Mommy be so proud of me";
    int count = 5;

    while (count != 0)
    {

        if (count == 5)
        {

            lyric = "bringing home ";
            endlyric = "OUCH!! It stung me!!";
            **OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;**
            count = count - 1;

        } else if (count == 4)
        {
            lyric = "squishin' ";
            endlyric = "ICK!! I feel sick!!";
            **OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;**
            count = count - 1;

        } else if (count == 3) {
            lyric = "barfin ";
            endlyric = "OH!! What a mess!!";
            OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;
            count = count - 1;
        }

        else if (count == 2)
        {
            lyric = "wipin' ";
            endlyric = "OOPS!! Mommy's new towel!!";
            **OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;**
            count = count - 1;
        }

        else if (count == 1)
        {
            lyric = "wringin' ";
            endlyric = "Bye-Bye baby "+userString+ "!!";
            **OneThree = "I'm " +lyric+ "my baby " +userString;**
            count = count - 1;
        }

        System.out.println(OneThree);
        System.out.println(Two);
        System.out.println(OneThree);
        System.out.println(endlyric);
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

}

Figured it out guys thanks lol.... feeling like a goof but i needed another set of eyes! :)